# form from model with multiple foreign keys in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a template that renders content filtered.

I used this Model to create the form (used to filter) :

```
class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'projectCategories'
        )
    parentCategory = models.ForeignKey(
        ParentCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Project categories"
```

Using a model form returns all the instance of the models ParentCategory and Category. What I want is to render only the values related to the projects.

I tried something like this :

```
class FilterbyCategory(forms.Form):
    parentCategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = ProjectCategory.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)",to_field_name="parentCategory")
```

But it doesn't work. Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it using value_list(), disctinct() and only() for queries optimization.

To retrieve Values of Categories and Parent Categories related to saved projects (you can replace id with name if you want names) :

```
projectCategories = ProjectCategory.objects.only('category','parentCategory').all()
categoryValues = projectCategories.values_list('category__id', flat=True).distinct()
parentCategoryValues = projectCategories.values_list('parentCategory__id', flat=True).distinct()
```

To retrieve Countries, Regions and Cities related to saved projects :

```
projectLocations = ProjectLocation.objects.only('country','region','city').all()
cityValues = projectLocations.values_list('city__id', flat=True).distinct()
regionValues = projectLocations.values_list('region__id', flat=True).distinct()
countryValues = projectLocations.values_list('country__id', flat=True).distinct()
```

Then, if you need to retrieve the objects of ParentCategory, you can use this query :

```
ParentCategory.objects.filter(id__in=parentCategoryValues)
```